# Firefox 4 refreshes all tabs although no Internet connection exists

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

Since updating to Firefox 4 I've had a problem:

With Firefox 3.x I could start it without a Internet connection and almost all of my open tabs were still loaded. With this I was able to read my open sites in the train where I have no Internet connection.

However this does not work in Firefox 4; if I launch Firefox 4 I see all my open tabs but the content is not available. It seems that the new version tries to refresh all tabs on startup.

Is it possible to disable this behaviour?

Comment: I do really miss that feature :-)

Comment: Maxim are u using normal version of Firefox or Portable one?

Comment: At the time I wrote the question I used the standard Firefox version which was shiped with Ubuntu 11.04. Now I updated to Firefox 5. The problem still exists

Comment: after I switched Options -> Advanced -> Network -> Uncheck Override Automatic Cache Management to Automatic from 0 it started to work. i use portable version of Firefox 7 for Windows

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you : start the Firefox profile manager as follows :

```
firefox.exe -ProfileManager  (Windows)
firefox -profilemanager      (Linux)
```

then "Start Firefox" for your profile after ticking "Work offine" :

[image]

Comment: Are you proposing that every time I start firefox I should use this?

Comment: Try once and see if the setting "sticks". If it doesn't stick, then the answer is yes. If it does stick, then on the other hand you will have to undo it to connect back.

Comment: Well this isn't what I want/need. In firefox 3.6 i could leave my tabs open and get back to it even without internet connection. It was just not refreshing things on start. Right now it does. I am not sure whether it's normal behaviour for 4+ or maybe it changed for portableapps firefox. Doing this thru profiles seems like an overkill.

Comment: You could use this method as a stopgap solution, while presenting the problem to the Firefox developers at [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/).

Comment: Are you seeing this problem too? I want to confirm that others in new versions have the same behaviour as I do. I use Portable version of Firefox 6 (aurora right now) but I've been using Portable version since 2.0 and till new 4.0 version it was working as explained by maxim.

Comment: No, I am not using this version. One more reason to contact the developers.

Comment: Would this apply to Mac / Linux? - I don't think so

Comment: @kalaracey: Right - I added the Linux call.

Comment: This workaround works for me. I am a Linux user, too.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your offline cache is enabled, it should be set to true by default.
In your address bar type:

> about:config

In the filter field type:

> browser.cache.offline.enable

Make sure this value is set to true (can be toggled by clicking on it).
You can do the same for "browser.cache.offline.capacity" which has a default value of 512000

Comment: This does not solve my problem. The offline cache is enabled and the cache size is 512000. The problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: OK, try this one, I'm not sure if it functions how you want it to:- back into about:config, find  network.manage-offline-status and set to true

Comment: I tested this setting but it still not works as I was used to it.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the problem myself but it seems that it started working again when I did:

`Options -> Advanced -> Network -> Uncheck Override Automatic Cache Management`. Before that it was `Checked` with `0`.

Please try it Maxim and let me know if it helps. Maybe it was some add-on I've installed recently (`Tab Mix Plus` comes to my mind - I wasn't using it for longer while after it was incompatible with 4.0 but now it is and installed it again). So it's either that setting or some this add-on (or both).

Comment: On my system I can not identify any difference when I switch this setting on or off.